# How filesystem knows where the end of files are (on a binary standpoint)

Tags: file, binary, filesystems, hex, storage

How does a file system know where the end of file begins and the next starts. Is there metadata that shows how big the file is? or is there a byte that represents an EOF? I did some hexdumps however and there seems to be no end of file bytes. Is there an index or something in a file system? It isn't about programming, just on a very low level-binary standpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File systems contain metadata that is used to determine where files begin and end.

In a filesystem like ext3, inodes are used:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode

In a FAT filesystem, there is a File Allocation Table near the beginning of the drive that maps hard drive addresses to files:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table